# Change django csrf token in ajax prefilter

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, cookies

Here are the thing I know -

1. There is @ensure_csrf_cookie over my view method which is loading a template.
2. In the template I need that csrf token, so I get it from the cookie and make a 3rd party api call.
3. From the 3rd party api call I get back that same csrf token.
4. There is ajax prefilter setup which is sending the csrf token from the browser cookie in all the ajax calls from that template.
5. But I want to send the csrf token I got from my 3rd party api call.

How do I override the ajax prefilter?

Let me know if this question seems correct. Or I am understanding this in the wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fix for me. Please see the steps below -

1. I imported from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect and placed a decorator @csrf_protect over the method which an api will from ajax calls in that template.
2. In an ajax call in that template for the method mentioned above, I have added

   headers: {
     "X-CSRFToken": [CSRF Token I Got FROM 3rd Party Api Call]
   }
3. In my ajax prefilters if have put a check if this header parameter is already set then stop it being set from the browser cookie.

   if(!options.headers["X-CSRFToken"])
     options.headers["X-CSRFToken"] = [CSRF Token from browser cookie];
   }